# I want to know in the 1st case the returned function is called as a middleware,,but in the 2nd case the returned function is not called

Tags: javascript, validation, middleware

CASE1 ... where the returned function by validatebody(schemas.authschema) is executed as a middleware...

```
router.route("/signup").post(validatebody(schemas.authschema),userscontrollers.signup);
```

My 2nd file which exports the function and schema of validators...

```
module.exports={
validatebody:function(schema)
{
    return function(req,res,next)
    {
        var result=joi.validate(req.body,schema);
        if(result.error)
          return res.status(400).json(result.error);

        
        if(!req.value)
            req.value={};
        
        req.value['body']=result.value;
        next();
    }
},

schemas:{
    authschema:joi.object().keys(
        {
               email:joi.string().email().required(),
               password:joi.string().required()
        })
}
};
```

NOW 2nd CASE....in this case I do not output anything and the page goes on loading for long because the function names second function is never called and next() is never triggered....but in the 1st case...the function which was returned was called..

```
app.get("/users",firstfunction,secondfunction);


function firstfunction()
{
    return function(req,res,next)
    {
        console.log(req);
        next();
    }
}

function secondfunction(req,res,next)
{
    res.send("go there");
}



app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in `firstfunction` but not calling it. You would need to do

```js
app.get("/users",firstfunction(),secondfunction);
```